# How to get element index when using a stream to traverse a list?

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to get index when traverse list use lambda.

For example:

```
List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = null;

checkBoxes.forEach(checkBox -> {
      if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
          sb.append("index"); //I want to get checkbox index here
          sb.append(",");
      }
});
```

**EDIT**: The `checkBoxes = null;` is just a placeholder but will be used properly once I start writing some code.

Comment: That code as is would totally throw a `Null pointer Exception`

Comment: lambda doesn't work for all cases but using a traditional `for` loop would be best for your case.

Comment: I know. It's just a example . I won't write like this in my code .

Comment: I need to generate corn expression for alarm that repeat in every week.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

Run an `IntStream` over the indexes of the list. Then *filter* the indexes based on whether the corresponding checkbox is selected. Then *map* the index value, an `int`, into a `String` representation of index value. Finally, collect the strings into a result string, separated by commas.

Code:

```
    String result = IntStream.range(0, checkBoxes.size())
                             .filter(i -> checkBoxes.get(i).isSelected())
                             .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

The output will be something like

```
    0,1,3,6
```

depending upon which checkboxes are actually checked.

I would avoid using `forEach` since you can accomplish the goal by transforming values instead of performing side effects. I would also avoid `List.indexOf` since that searches the list linearly for the desired item. It's not a big deal if you have only a few checkboxes, but if you have a lot, the O(N^2) growth will cause performance to suffer.

Comment: Your answer has great value to me , but what makes me headache is it requires API 24.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using `IntStream`:

```
List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = //data

IntStream.range(0, checkBoxes.size())
.forEach(i -> {
   CheckBox checkbox = checkBoxes.get(i); 
    if(checkbox.isSelected()){
        sb.append(i);
        sb.append(",");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please keep your lambda short and like one liner maybe

Answer (score 1):

try

```
List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = null;
checkBoxes.forEach(checkBox -> {
    if(checkBox.isSelected()){
        index = checkBoxes.indexOf(checkBox);
        sb.append(index); //I want to get checkbox index here
        sb.append(",");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

lambda *doesn't* work for all cases, I would recommend using a traditional for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size(); i++){
    if(checkBoxes.get(i).isSelected()){
         // simply use "i" in this case for the index
         sb.append(i); //I want to get checkbox index here
         sb.append(",");
     }
}
```

However, if you insist on using streams you'll need to use the `indexOf` method provided by the `List` to get the corresponding index for that particular element.

```
checkBoxes.forEach(checkBox ->{
    if(checkBox.isSelected()){
          int indexValue = checkBoxes.indexOf(checkBox);
          sb.append(indexValue); //I want to get checkbox index here
          sb.append(",");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options that weren't raised:

1.. Using a wrapping stream and a pair:

```
public static <T> Stream<Pair<Integer, T>> createIndexedStream(Stream<T> stream) {
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    return stream.map(t -> Pair.of(count.getAndIncrement(), t));
}
```

Usage eample:

```
    List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c");
    createIndexedStream(list.stream())
            .forEach(pair -> System.out.println("Index: " + pair.getLeft() + ". Value: " + pair.getRight()));
```

2.. External counter:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
list.stream().map(s -> Pair.of(count.getAndIncrement(), s))
        .forEach(pair -> System.out.println("Index: " + pair.getLeft() + ". Value: " + pair.getRight()));
```

or

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
list.stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println("Index: " + count.getAndIncrement() + ". Value: " + s));
```

* Would be nice to use BiFunction/BiConsumer/etc. but I couldn't figure how.